# Is there a word for person who is obsessed with scores

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

Is there a word for a person who is very eager to earn points or scores? Not only in some academic field but everywhere, like sports or even if they join Stack Exchange, they start concentrating on getting reputation rather than on helping people.

Comment: I'd like to downvote this question because it doesn't interest me, but I can't bear to lose a rep point when I'm *so* close to reaching 100K! :)

Comment: Isn't the point of reputation systems to encourage such (point-whores)? to help people?

Comment: ... FumbleFingers?

Comment: @DigitalChris Competitive is some one who wants more point in comparison of others. I am looking for someone who just want to score. Like i gave example of rep in Stack Exchange, there one is not being competitive, while wants have more points.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you only lose rep for downvoting answers, not questions. ;)

Comment: In academia it is called 'grade-grubbing', but that doesn't translate to outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most accurate term is point-whore. This is a term common to tabletop gaming and computer gaming. This type of person only plays in order to get the most points or highest score in the game. Often this type of player even sabotages the game in order to end up with more points than the others.

Answer (score 2):

Pathologically competitive would be my description of such a person, but that is two words and you asked for "a word."

As far as "not being competitive while wants to have more points" -- more points than whom? If he is  not competing, the points wouldn't mean anything. It's obviously a competition in his mind.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking of a term called: score keeper

Comment: A score-keeper is normally one who keeps a record of the score for others (during a game, for instance), not someone who obsesses about *his own* score. But I suppose it might be used as an extension of its usual sense.

Answer (score -1):

In cricket such a person is known as a *statistician*.

This is a common species, obsessed with the scores of everyone in every team, throughout history.

A true cricket statistician can recite the top ten scores by a number nine on a Saturday in Yorkshire since 1872.  They are often found around the ground recording every ball's delivery and stroke.  Then in a pub later discussing their favourite numbers.

And of course, they all worship at the altar of the great [Bill Frindall](http://www.beardedwonder.co.uk/).  A legend amongst cricketers everywhere.

Comment: That's not what the question asks for.